# JS calendar push data to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, calendar

I'am trying to use simple js calendar the problem is i don't know how to push data for him it's using json object when i create variable with one object everything is fine, but when i wanna pass array with objects through ajax I 'am strugling. Example below works fine, but my purpose is to get data from ajax like [{..},{..},{..},{..}] how can i push array with objects to events array : []

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var svente1 =
        {
            startDate: '2021-06-03',
            endDate: '2021-06-03',
            summary: 'Pasaulinė dviračio diena'
        }
        $("#calendar").simpleCalendar({
            //Defaults options below
            //string of months starting from january
            months: ['sausis', 'vasaris', 'kovas', 'balandis', 'gegužė', 'birželis', 'liepa', 'rugpjūtis', 'rugsėjis', 'spalis', 'lapkritis', 'gruodis'],
            days: ['sekmadienis', 'pirmadienis', 'antradienis', 'trečiadienis', 'ketvirtadienis', 'penktadienis', 'šeštadienis'],
            displayYear: true,              // Display year in header
            fixedStartDay: true,            // Week begin always by monday or by day set by number 0 = sunday, 7 = saturday, false = month always begin by first day of the month
            displayEvent: true,             // Display existing event
            disableEventDetails: false, // disable showing event details
            disableEmptyDetails: true, // disable showing empty date details
            events: [svente1],                     // List of events
            onInit: function (calendar) { }, // Callback after first initialization
            onMonthChange: function (month, year) { }, // Callback on month change
            onDateSelect: function (date, events) { }, // Callback on date selection
            onEventSelect: function () { }, // Callback on event selection - use $(this).data('event') to access the event
            onEventCreate: function ($el) { },          // Callback fired when an HTML event is created - see $(this).data('event')
            onDayCreate: function ($el, d, m, y) { }  // Callback fired when an HTML day is created   - see $(this).data('today'), .data('todayEvents')
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just removed brackets and passed variable. Data which i get from Ajax need to use command json.parse